# Browser address autofill does not fill a "state" SelectField element

Tags: material-ui, autofill

I have an address form where for the "state" two letter code, I use material-ui SelectField.
Problem is that this SelectField does not autofill with the correct state code, when the browser proposes an autofill address.
All other text fields (address, city, zip-code) autofill correctly.
I've tested this with Chrome/Firefox/IE/Edge/Safari.

You can test my code here: https://gmacciocca.github.io/coffee-with-congress

Answer (score 1):

This is because `SelectField` is composed of `<div>`s etc. rather than using a native `<select>` form element.

A hidden shadow element could in theory be used to capture the input, buts some browser don't trigger DOM events on autofill as a security precaution, so it wouldn't be possible to determine that a value had been provided without continuous polling.

This is the same issue we have with the text field label not animating on autofill.